# CS0304: "Невозможно создать экземпляр типа переменной type, потому что он не имеет ограничения new ()"

Tags: c#, generics

Если я напишу вот такой элементарный код

```
    class MyClass<T>  {

        private T val;
        
        public MyClass() {
            val = new T();
        }
    
    }
```

то он не скомпилируется с ошибкой, котрая написана в заголовке вопроса.

И я могу исправить это, написав ограничение

```
    class MyClass<T> where T : new() {

        private T val;
        
        public MyClass() {
            val = new T();
        }
    
    }
```

Но есть вопрос.

*я не понимаю, зачем это ограничение нужно*.

То есть, я не могу себе представить ситуацию, когда у класса Т не может быть вызыван new(T)

Я рассуждаю так: если T - это ref type, то он наследуется от Object

У Object возможность вызвать new() - есть.

Значит, у T такая возможность тоже есть.

Но ограничение, наверное, придумали не просто так.

Нельзя ли пояснить подробнее, зачем оно нужно?

Comment: конструктор по умолчанию есть не везде. То, что он есть у Object абсолютно не означает, что он должен быть у всех наследников Object

Comment: сделайте `class TestClass { public TestClass(int i) {} }` и попробуйте вызвать у него конструтор по умолчанию или использовать в своем классе и увидите.

Comment: также это ограничение требует, чтобы конструктор был публичный (т.е. от может существовать, но помечен другим модификатором доступа)

Comment: Большое спасибо, после комментариев всё стало понятнее. я не подумал ни про отсутствие конструктора по умолчанию, ни про модификаторы доступа.